# Access specific value of select element using Mootools

Tags: html, mootools

I've got a select element in my HTML page and I'd like to do a specific action using Mootools when a particular value of this select is chosen but I don't know how to access the element.

My element has cars_number as id and to access value 1 of this select element I've tried cars_number[1] but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
$('cars_number').getSelected();
```

[MooTools Documentation](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3agetSelected)